# Insert record to BigQuery streaming vs simple insert - using table->insertRow or table->inserRows vs using bigquery->runquery

Tags: google-bigquery, streaming

If I use  table->insertRow() or table->inserRows() functions, that means I am streaming data into bigquery.

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.53.0/bigquery/table

But if I use bigquery->runQuery() function to run the insert statements, that is not streaming.

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.53.0/bigquery/bigqueryclient?method=runQuery

In what case I should using streaming to insert data? and in what case, I should use bigquery runQuery to run a insert statement?

Thanks!

Comment: DML (insert) comes with hard quoats e.g. 1000 per table per day (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#data_manipulation_language_statements). You wouldn't use this for getting large amounts of data into BigQuery. Instead, you'd use streaming for this. Two completely different things that solve different problems.

Comment: Thanks!

I have been using streaming, or upload from cloud, or insert select etc. before. Not use DML (insert). 

Now, I facing a small issue, I need to see the data right away after I insert it. Using streaming, sometimes the data is still in buffer.

Maximum UPDATE/DELETE statements per day per table — 96
Maximum UPDATE/DELETE statements per day per project — 10,000
Maximum INSERT statements per day per table — 1,000

Yes.  insert statement could be easy to over 1000.

Comment: Even if it's in the buffer, it's still available to be queried.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just as a complement to the answer that @GrahamPolley provided in the comments to your question (and for the sake of having an answer that is more accessible for the community), let me share some documentation links that may be useful for the questions that you made in this post.

### ***Streaming Inserts vs. DML Insert***

Streaming inserts use the [`tabledata.insertAll` method](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll) to insert one record at a time in a table, and it does not require that a load job is run. In [this documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery), you can find all the information related to Streaming Inserts, its features, limitations, and quotas.

As stated in the comment to your question, using DML inserts you can only perform [1000 INSERT queries per table per day](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#data_manipulation_language_statements) (and [the same limit applies to load jobs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs) too), while for streaming inserts, you [don't have a limit per day](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#streaming_inserts), and only maximum rows per second and request.

### ***Data availability***

Data that is streamed into BigQuery is available shortly (within a few seconds) after the first streaming insertion in a table, even if it is in the buffer. However, [this data may be unavailable for other operations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataavailability) (such as copy, export or even [some API methods like `tabledata.list`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors#missingunavailable-data)), so if you are performing any of those, you will first have to check that the buffer is empty. You can do that by checking the response from `tables.get` in a section named `streamingBuffer`, which should be empty is the buffer is empty.