# BigQuery Steaming data into tables and select from these tables

Tags: google-bigquery, streaming

How long I have to wait after I stream data to a bigquery table before I can select data from it?

Even the data are still in streaming buffer I could select the data without worrying about losing the data that still in buffer.

But it seems I did select right after streaming, I lost some data.

So here are the statements in this order, executed right after each other.

1. Create Table A. Stream data into table A
2. Create Table B. Stream data into table B
3. Create Table C. Stream data into table C
4. Create Table D. Process table C data and select data from table C, insert the select results into Table D
5. Delete Table E if it exists. Re-Create Table E. Join query select from table A, B and D, insert the query result into Table E. Count Table E. The count for example is 200,000.

Now, a few minutes later. I would only re-run the step 5

```
Delete Table E if it exists. Re-Create Table E. Join query select from table A, B and D, insert the query result into Table E. Count Table E.
```

Due to table A, B and D are still the same, I should get the same count as previous count, for example 200,000. But the count I got this time is more than 200,000. It has a few hundred more records than previous count, for example 200,200 records.

Now  I would only re-run the step 5 again.

This time, I would get 200,200 records again.

It seems first time, I did select statement right after streaming data. I kind lost 200 records. The second time and third time, I had waited for a few minutes before I select from the tables that might be still getting data from streaming buffer, I got the full sets data.

In other words

1. Select right after streaming data, I would lose some records.
2. Wait for a few minutes after streaming, select. Then I would get the full set data without losing any records.

Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: _"How long I have to wait after I stream data to a bigquery table before I can select data from it?"_: it's available for immediate analysis (within a few secs). See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48797143/insert-record-to-bigquery-streaming-vs-simple-insert-using-table-insertrow-or

Answer (score 0):

Just as @GrahamPolley stated in his comment, all data coming from a streaming insert are available for querying a few seconds after the stream is complete. There are some circumstances, such as an outage, that may prevent this from happening, but the queries will still be successful as they will skip some data still in the streaming buffer.

This has already been explained in the question linked by Graham, but just in case I'm going to refer you back to the Google Cloud documentation regarding this subject. You can find the information about data availability [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataavailability).

You can also check this article to better understand how [BigQuery streaming](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/06/life-of-a-bigquery-streaming-insert) works.

If you wish to know about a more precise amount of time to wait in order to obtain the full query results after streaming, it will depend on some factors such as how far the streaming buffer is from the query tree, which format is used to store the data, and if it is possible to run the operations in parallel.